# How to detect current active page in Property sheet (C++/VS)

Tags: c++, winapi, propertysheet

I am using Visual Studio C++ 2010, and I need to detect current active page of Property Sheet. I expect there should be send some message to tell when user activated the Page. But I did not found that message and where to place it in dialog process.

In the program which I work with, there is this main dialog process:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK MainDlgProc(HWND hSheet, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    INT_PTR ret = FALSE;

    switch (msg)
    {
    // bla bla
    case WM_COMMAND:
        ret = 0;    //processing message
        if (!Sheet_HandleCommand(hSheet, HIWORD(wParam), LOWORD(wParam), (HWND)lParam))
            CALLPROC();
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        // bla bla
        return CALLPROC();    
    default:
        return CALLPROC();
    }

    return ret;
}
```

I know how to get the handle but I don't know where to "install" it in the code. What's the name of the message to include it into the MainDlgProc?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`PSM_GETTABCONTROL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774580(v=vs.85).aspx) (or the `PropSheet_GetTabControl` macro) to get a handle to the tab control, and then use the [`TCM_GETCURSEL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760583(v=vs.85).aspx) message (or the `TabCtrl_GetCurSel` macro) to query the currently selected tab index.

Note this is documented not to work if using the Aero wizard style (`PSH_AEROWIZARD`), presumably because there is no tab control in that case.

Comment: Where exactly should I use this message? Can I use it in main dialog process function? Or should this go to the dialog process of the Property sheet? Should I place it under case WM_COMMAND: or case WM_NOTIFY:?

Comment: @user1141649 I don't understand the question. Use it wherever and whenever you need to determine the current tab.

Comment: This fails, the result of "test" variable is 0. But I clicked on 5th tab (#4): `INT_PTR CALLBACK MainDlgProc(HWND hSheet, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    INT_PTR ret = FALSE;
    HWND test;
      switch (msg)
        {
 case WM_NOTIFY: 
  test = PropSheet_GetTabControl(hSheet);
  propdata.activePropSheetPage = TabCtrl_GetCurSel(PropSheet_GetTabControl(hSheet));
 break;
        }
 return ret;
}`

Comment: @user1141649 You are sending the message to yourself (`hSheet`) not to the property sheet. The `PSM_GETTABCONTROL` message is a property sheet message; send it to the property sheet. (Also, it's not clear why you called your main dialog `hSheet`. You are not the property sheet.)

Comment: @RaymondChen: The hSheet is defined under int WINAPI WinMain():`hSheet = (HWND)PropertySheet(&header);` and there is also this: `pproc = (DLGPROC)SetWindowLong(hSheet, DWL_DLGPROC, (LONG)&MainDlgProc);`. So it is handle to the Property Sheet.